# struct run method everytime a value has changed

Tags: c++, struct

I'm pretty new to structs in C++ (and a C++ noob in general).

I want to build a struct which holds the configuration for my application. Everytime I set the value of a configuration-parameter, I want to check if the configuration is still valid (e.g. all values don't exceed the given bounds etc.). For that, I've programmed a isValid-function which checks that.

Here is a minimal version of my current version of the code:

```cpp
// CameraConfig.h
struct CameraConfig {
    int brightness;
    int contrast;
    int specialEffect;
    // and so on

    bool isValid();
};
```

```cpp
// CameraConfig.cpp
bool CameraConfig::isValid() {
    if (brightness < -2 || brightness > 2) return false;
    if (contrast < -2 || contrast > 2) return false;
    if (specialEffect < 0 || specialEffect > 6) return false;
    return true
}
```

Right now, the checks dont depend on each other, but I'm pretty sure they will in the future. Is there a way to run this everytime a value is set? I've thought about setter-functions, but those would become messy when values depend on each other and so on, right?

I'm coming from python, so here is a way I would implement it there:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any


@dataclass
class CameraConfig:
    brightness: int
    contrast: int
    special_effect: int

    def isValid(self) -> bool:
        return (
            self.brightness >= 0
            and self.brightness <= 100
            and self.contrast >= 0
            and self.contrast <= 100
            and self.special_effect >= 0
            and self.special_effect <= 6
        )

    def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: Any) -> None:
        prev = getattr(self, name)
        super().__setattr__(name, value)
        if not self.isValid():
            super().__setattr__(name, prev)
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid value for {name}: {value}")
```

I know this is not the most elegant way to solve it, but it works.
**What is the way to do that in C++?**

Comment: [Automatically call function when variable changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159165/automatically-call-function-when-variable-changes)

Comment: I know that C++ is a very different language, but I thought about how I would do it and thats what I came up with...

Comment: Looks like a good dupe: [C++ - Function calling when changing member value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9144819/c-function-calling-when-changing-member-value) and [Observing change in value of member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880253/observing-change-in-value-of-member-variable)

Comment: I have no idea what the python code is doing in terms of what you are trying to accomplish, but as the duplicate link suggests, you should take a step back and think of *design patterns*, namely the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Comment: For explanation, the python code is doing the following steps:
1. Saving the current value
2. Setting the attribute via calling the __setattr__()-method of the superclass
3. Checking if the configuration is still valid
    - If not, reset to the previous value and raise an error.

__setattr__() is called everytime any value in the class is set.

Comment: Make things private and create setters for each variable. In each setter, call the method.

Comment: C++ deliberately doesn't have what you wrote in Python. Even if you managed to find some workaround, it will be terrible because no one expects it.

Comment: So a setter would look something like this?: bool CameraConfig::setBrightness(int brightness)
{
    int prev = this->brightness;
    this->brightness = brightness;
    if (isValid())
        return true;
    // resetting to previous value if new value is invalid
    this->brightness = prev;
    return false;
}

Comment: @HomerusJa Yes.